# How to check if a template argument is default constructible

Tags: c++, templates, implementation

I am writing a template class and want to find out whether template argument is [default constructible](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/DefaultConstructible.html) is there any way to do it ?

The code is something like following

```
template <class C>
class A
{

createObj()
{
C* objPtr = NULL;
// If default constructible then create object else let it remain NULL
}
};
```

Update: I have tried using [code given in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733377/can-a-trait-state-if-a-c-class-has-a-default-constructor/2770326#2770326) but it doesn't work, to be precise if return default constructible even for those classes which aren't, I have no idea why is that happening.

Comment: I'm not that sure what do you mean..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a trait state if a C++ class has a default constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733377/can-a-trait-state-if-a-c-class-has-a-default-constructor)

Comment: @CashCow There was no definitive answer to that question so asking again.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classical case for [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE) and [`enable_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html).

In another answer, Potatoswatter has already posted a type trait [`is_default_constructible`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733377/can-a-trait-state-if-a-c-class-has-a-default-constructor/2770326#2770326) that can be reused here:

```
void createObj(
    typename enable_if_c<is_default_constructible<C>::value, void>::type* dummy = 0)
{
     C* objPtr = new C();
}

void createObj(
    typename disable_if_c<is_default_constructible<C>::value, void>::type* dummy = 0)
{
     C* objPtr = 0;
}
```

Or, if your function has a non-void return type `T` (thanks to DeadMG) you can omit the dummy default argument:

```
typename enable_if_c<is_default_constructible<C>::value, T>::type createObj()
{
     C* objPtr = new C();
}

typename disable_if_c<is_default_constructible<C>::value, T>::type createObj()
{
     C* objPtr = 0;
}
```

SFINAE means that a template which cannot be instantiated for a given type, will not. `enable_if_c` basically results in a valid type if and only if its argument is `true`. Now we use the metafunction `is_default_constructible` to test whether the type `C` has a default constructor. If so, `enable_if_c<…>::type` will result in a valid type, otherwise it will not.

The C++ compiler will thus only see one of the two functions, to wit the one that is usable in your context. See the documentation of `enable_if` for more details.

Comment: Why not use enable_if on the return type and prevent the necessity of the dummy argument? Also, I believe you require a `typename` in there.

Comment: @DeadMG: because this only works for non-`void`. The OP hasn’t specified a return type …

Comment: @Konrad I didn't get the code, can you write in detail, also I can't use boost. Thanks

Comment: @Gaurav: if you cannot use Boost, just copy the header of the `enable_if` template.

Comment: @Konrad I tried to use is_default_constructible but it is not working. Specifically I am getting def const even for classes which aren't Any idea what might be the problem :-(.  Thanks.

Comment: @Gaurav: sorry … :-( Apparently this requires compiler support that is only available in very few compilers, see [Boost.TypeTraits: `has_trivial_constructor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_trivial_constructor.html). There doesn’t seem to be a good solution then.

Comment: has_trivial_constructor is not the same as this though. We want to know if there is an accessible default constructor and not whether it is trivial.

Comment: Does that code actually work? If they aren't template functions, then why won't it simply be a compile error? (something like missing type - defaulting to int)

Comment: @doug65536 They aren’t function templates but they are functions that depend on a template argument nevertheless (because they are member functions of a class template) so this will work. What you get is a template argument substitution failure and that is *not* an error (SFINAE).

Comment: So being a member of a template class already qualifies it for SFINAE to work? Does it work because it has another alternative that does work when the substitution failure is in error (and the overload is not considered) and vice versa when the bool condition is reversed?

Comment: @doug65536 Yes: SFINAE is used in the context of overload resolution. In the case of substitution failure in a function, that candidate function is simply removed from the set of possible overloads to consider.

Comment: I think you just nailed my issues with it! You always have to have another alternative that IS allowed. When the compiler has no alternative, it complains about the SFINAE overload, right?

Comment: @doug65536 Well if there’s no valid overload the compiler complains that it cannot find a function for the required call, like it would do if you would call an undeclared function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of SFINAE, you use a function overload, one that takes ... as a parameter, one that calls the method you are looking for.

In any case this particular question is answered `[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733377/can-a-trait-state-if-a-c-class-has-a-default-constructor)