# Which temporaries cannot be initialized with `someType()` in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

I have some macros which operate on types and initial values. I need to cast the initial value `vIni` to the `vType` (`vIni` is always convertible to `vType`, sometimes it has the same type). The `vIni` might be empty as well, in which case `vType` should be uninitialized or default-initialized. The reult is passed to templated function.

In short,

```
template<typename T> void foo(const T& o);

foo(vType(vIni));
foo(vType());
```

must compile.

I already discovered that `foo(unsigned int())` or `foo(int*())` will not compile, but it can be worked around with a typedef.

What are other cases (besides built-in types with spaces and pointers) which will fail?

Comment: Obviously, `void()`, but that's got more to do with the fact that you can't have `void` objects than the precise syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669131/how-to-check-if-a-template-argument-is-default-constructible, also cf. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig: that's not what this question is about as far as I can tell. This isn't really about the type itself, it's about how the type is named (hence, "can be worked around with a typedef"). Certainly the answer to that supposed dupe doesn't answer this question at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short (slightly over-simplified) answer is, "it will fail for anything other than a simple-type-specifier".

5.2.3/1 says:

> A *simple-type-speciﬁer* (7.1.6.2) or *typename-speciﬁer* (14.6) followed
>   by a parenthesized *expression-list* constructs a value of the speciﬁed
>   type given the expression list.

A *simple-type-specifier* can be either a one-word name for a type (optionally plus some `::` stuff for the scope, and/or template arguments which themselves need not be simple type specifiers) or a `decltype` expression. The possibilities are listed in 7.1.6.2.

`unsigned int` and `int*` aren't *simple-type-specifiers*. Any compound type specifier will fail, so cv-qualification, array types, function types, pointer types including pointer-to-function and pointer-to-member would all need a typedef.

Also ruled out are the multi-word type identifiers like `unsigned char`, `long double`. For your first example, `unsigned` would work in place of `unsigned int`.

A *typename-specifier* is a type preceded by `typename`, used in templates to assert that a dependent name is indeed a type, not a data member or member function.

Finally of course, once you get past this restriction the type has to actually be constructible or convertible from the *expression-list*. So for example you can't create a temporary of function type using this or any other syntax.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, template compound types do work: `std::vector<unsigned int>()`. Per 7.1.6.2, a _simple-template-id_ is a _simple-type-specifier_

Comment: People often create an alias<T> or identit<T> type for such uses, i.e., `alias<unsigned int>::type()`

Comment: @DeadMG: yep, that's better than my thing involving `declspec`.

Comment: Note that you also cannot create a temporary array without such an `alias`. :) `auto&& arr = alias<int[]>{1, 2, 3};`