# Checking if a class has a copy constructor with TMP

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae, pointer-to-member

I've been attempting a little SFINAE at making a way to determine if a generic type T has a copy constructor I can use.  Here is where I currently am.

```
template <bool statement, typename out>
struct Failable
{
    typedef out Type;
};
//This class is only used to insert statements that 
//could encounter substitution failure


template <typename O>
struct COPY
{
    template <typename T>
    typename Failable<true == sizeof(&T::T(const T&)), char>::Type copy(int)
    {}

    template <typename T>
    typename Failable<true, int>::Type copy(...)
    {}

};
```

However, this is also where I'm kinda stuck.  `&T::T(const T&)` is obviously an invalid statement, as we can't provide an argument list with a pointer-to-member, even if a p-t-m-function.
I could always try to specify some sort of `void (T::*ptmf)(const T&) = &T::T`, and hope it implicitly determines the right overloaded constructor to put into the pointer to member function, but that also implies that Constructors have a specific return type, which I would have to specify.

Does anyone else have any ideas with which I can trek forth? (I also need to apply a similar concept to checking for an assignment operator.)

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [std::is_copy_constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible) and [std::is_assignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable) for this.

Comment: ...why is it that a potentially difficult question just has to have easy answers? *sigh*
Thanks for letting me know about this!  I'm hoping to see if there's a way to implement it manually, though =)

Comment: @Serge: you might look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733377/is-there-a-way-to-test-whether-a-c-class-has-a-default-constructor-other-than/2770326#2770326 - change the test to something like `sizeof U(*(U*)0))` (note `U(U())` also requires default constructibility so isn't good).

Answer (score 2):

You can do with your code, just need to modify it a little bit.

```
template <bool statement, typename out>
struct Failable
{
     typedef out Type;
}; 

template <typename O>
struct COPY
{

     static O MakeO();

     template <typename U> // U and T are the same type
     static typename Failable<(sizeof U(MakeO())), char>::Type copy(int);

     template <typename U>
     static typename Failable<true, int>::Type copy(...);

     enum { value = sizeof(char) == sizeof( copy<O>(0) ) };
};
```

Comment: I tried to use this solution as I need to use an old g++. If the copy ctor is private an error message is presented `error: 'CA::CA(const CA&)' is private. Could it be avoided? Otherwise how could it be that there is no copy ctor?

Comment: Actually it does work with g++ 4.7+. At first I tried with 4.1.2 and it failed. THX!

Comment: `// U and T are the same type`  Where's `T`?  Do you mean `O`?

Comment: The COPY<std::stringstream>::value will be 1 but std::stringstream has no copy ctor. I think this template class is correct and it is a strange feature of STL. Why is COPY<std::stringstream>::value == 1?