# Is there a way to test that a default constructor does not exist?

Tags: c++, testing, c++03

I am writing a test driver for a type this is explicitly supposed to not be default constructable. Is there any way to assert in my test driver that this is the case? I can verify manually via compilation errors, but I want something that will protect against future changes that may misguidedly add a default constructor.

Edit: I'm stuck in an environment with C++03. Keeping that in mind, are there any other options than `is_default_constructable`?

Comment: I don't get it. Why will verification via compilation errors *not* protect you against future changes?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: It's difficult to automate the test, and check that compilation is failing for the right reason.

Comment: What I mean is that I can cause an error by trying to use the default constructor to verify one does not exist. I obviously can't leave that error in the code.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: He means he could _only_ test it manually, so the test would not be in his automated regression test suite and it would be easy to forget to re-run the manual test for future versions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, he could add a meta step to his tests and test compiler invocations. But as Mike Seymour said above, this would prove very complicated.

Comment: @Christian: Yes it would be silly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `static_assert(!std::is_default_constructible<T>::value, "Boo");`. Make sure to `#include <type_traits>`.

Comment: Makes me really wish I had access to C++11 :(. Is there any way to do this in C++03?

Comment: @GBleaney: Hm, maybe there's some kind of SFINAE trick with defaulted arguments that might work. Let me try.

Comment: @GBleaney: Try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733377/is-there-a-way-to-test-whether-a-c-class-has-a-default-constructor-other-than/2770326).